# Large numbers get converted to NaN when stored in multi-dimensional arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the actual code excerpt where I am facing problem:

```
var p = {x:400, y:100, z:100};
var c = {x:250, y:250, z:100};
var o = {x:250, y:250, z:250};
var ta = 1;
var r1 = 212.13203435596427;
var r2 = 259.8076211353316;
var b1 = Math.round(2*r1*r1*(1 - Math.cos(ta)) - r2*r2 + (o.x+p.x)*(o.x-p.x) + (o.y+p.y)*(o.y-p.y) + (o.z+p.z)*(o.z-p.z));
var b2 = Math.round(r1*r1*(1 - 2*Math.cos(ta)) + (c.x+p.x)*(c.x-p.x) + (c.y+p.y)*(c.y-p.y) + (c.z+p.z)*(c.z-p.z));
var b3 = Math.round((r2+r1)*(r2-r1) + (c.x+o.x)*(c.x-o.x) + (c.y+o.y)*(c.y-o.y) + (c.z+o.z)*(c.z-o.z));
var A = [ [2*(o.x - p.x), 2*(o.y - p.y), 2*(o.z - p.z)],
          [2*(c.x - p.x), 2*(c.y - p.y), 2*(c.z - p.z)],
          [2*(c.x - o.x), 2*(c.y - o.y), 2*(c.z - o.z)]
        ];
A[0][3] = b1;
A[1][3] = b2;
A[2][3] = b3;
console.log(A[0]);
console.log(A[1]);
console.log(A[2]);
console.log(A);
```

As yet the code works pretty fine:
[image: Actual image on running the code segment]

Then I add this line just after the above code.

```
var sol = gauss(A);
```

Now when I run this, on the console:

[image: actual image of the google chrome console]

Please notice that four values get turned to NaN unlike in the first screenshot. Why does this happen, and how do I prevent this?

Comment: in case you think the error is in gauss() function here's the source:[link](http://martin-thoma.com/solving-linear-equations-with-gaussian-elimination/#tocAnchor-1-4)

Comment: what does gauss do? please post that code too

Comment: Put the gauss() source in the question. This surely comes from that function.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I posted it. Please see it and help me.

Comment: It's pretty sure the problem is with your gauss and not the js engine, since it sets the values to infinite if you exceed the limit (which is unlike btw). The gauss writes the Array. Check every point where it does, so you can debug the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might very well be that your calculations make numbers too large to be counted as a number.

You might want to look into a library like bigint.js

http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html

But the error might more be in the gauss function. It seems like a matrix calulation function, but somewhere it's dividing or multiplying something and goes way off the scale with it's values.

even gauss[1,1,1] produces a NaN

I don't have the time at this moment to step through it, but if someone else hasn't done this later on I will see if i can help with this.

Comment: no not at all. see the console screenshot i have posted.

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem lies in the gauss function. there is an error in there somewhere. If no-one has helped you later on I will try to help, but that this moment I don't have the time.

Comment: Also I suggest you edit your question to be about the Guass function. To prevent futher close votes.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was in gauss(). I rectified it. I am very thankful to you @MichaelDibbets.